# Does my follower get notified if I changed my name on Quora

Tags: quora

If I change my name on Quora, my profile link https://www.quora.com/some-user-2 (just an example) also get change.

So, does my followers get any notification (via email or Quora notification) about this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. As of now Quora doesn't send any notification to your followers if you change your name or update your profile.

Source: Self tested.